# bind Data using json mehod and js

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I am trying to retrieve data to   dropdownlist,
using json,
the program works but the dropdownlist displays a white list, by inspecting, the data is there but it is not displayed

Controller:

```
    public IActionResult GetClient()
    {
        var clientList = (from client in _context.Clients
                          select new SelectListItem()
                          {
                              Text = client.Nom,
                              Value = client.Id.ToString(),
                          }).ToList();

        clientList.Insert(0, new SelectListItem()
        {
            Text = "----Select----",
            Value = string.Empty
        });

        return Json(clientList);
    }
```

script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "/Clients/GetClient",
            success: function (data) {
                $.each(data, function () {
                    $("#ClientId").append($("<option></option>").val(this['Value']).html(this['Text']));

                });

            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

le code Html:

```
                </div>
                <div class="alert-danger" asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly"></div>
                <label asp-for="ClientId"></label>
                <select asp-for="ClientId"
                        class="form-control"
                        asp-items="@(new SelectList(Enumerable.Empty<SelectListItem>(),"Value", "Text"))">
                </select>
            </div>

            <div>
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: Is there anything else that I can help you with?

Answer (score 0):

> The dropdownlist displays a white list, by inspecting, the data is there but it is not displayed

The problem is very obvious. If you inspect the HTML you would be seen. The `value`  and `text` in lowercase but you have used on your code in uppercase that is `val(this['Value']).html(this['Text']))`.
As you might know JSON object keys are lowercase by default.

[image]

**Note:** Just replace below snippet so that it will resolve your problem completely.

**Solution:**

```
  $("#ClientId").append($("<option></option>").val(this['value']).html(this['text']));
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, it works well,
the objective is that each time the client is updated, the Dom updates the ddl, but this still does not work.
if there is something to do in the code?
I will be thankfull
Regards

Comment: Is there anything else that I can help you with?